# Spring Security, How we can create authorization rules antmatchers dynamically from database

Tags: spring-security

Is it a good practice to store authorization rules antmatchers URLs and Role in database and create dynamically on server start?

When a request comes to application does it fetch rules every time from database in Configure method of the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter if we use create them by fetching from database.

I'm not able to find any example that how we can create new rules dynamically just from database without changing application code.

Here is the sample code that I want to create rules dynamically

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/dashboard/**").hasAuthority("VIEW_DASHBOARD")
    .antMatchers("/dashboard/**").hasAuthority("EDIT_DASHBOARD")
    .antMatchers("/dashboard/**").hasAuthority("DELETE_DASHBOARD")
    .antMatchers("/profiling/**").hasAuthority("VIEW_PROFILING")
    .antMatchers("/profiling/**").hasAuthority("EDIT_PROFILING")
    .antMatchers("/profiling/**").hasAuthority("DELETE_PROFILING");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create your **AccessDecisionVoter**

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // you can inject AccessDecisionVoter in spring container
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<?>> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<>();
        decisionVoters.add(new AccessDecisionVoter<FilterInvocation>() {
            @Override
            public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public int vote(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation invocation, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
                String url = invocation.getRequestUrl();
                AntPathMatcher m = new AntPathMatcher();
                Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
                boolean matched = false;
                // you can retrieve url pattern from database here
                if (m.match("/**", url) && CollectionUtils.isEmpty(authorities) == false) {
                    matched = authorities.stream().anyMatch(a -> {
                        return a.getAuthority().equals("your_authority");
                    });
                }
                if (matched) {
                    return AccessDecisionVoter.ACCESS_GRANTED;
                } else {
                    return AccessDecisionVoter.ACCESS_DENIED;
                }
            }
        });
        AffirmativeBased aa = new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
        http.authorizeRequests().accessDecisionManager(aa);
    }
}
```